# Corporate Intranet on IIS 7: Looking to Enhance Directory Listing

Tags: css, iis, web-config, windows-server-2012-r2, directory-listing

I am looking for the ability to enhance the appearance of the directory listing pages of a very basic corporate intranet I developed for use by our employees. I am using Windows Server 2012 R2, and the site is deployed in Internet Information Services.

I did not use anything like Visual Studio to create this, and I have already handwritten all of the CSS and HTML for the index page that serves as a jump-off point for the rest of the site so that users can get to the content they need; however, the directory listings pages where the users land leave quite a bit to be desired to say the least.

I just want to be able to add some quick styles to these directories, such as modifying the font family and perhaps the link styles. Nothing major, really. The site already functions perfectly for what it was designed to do, and has been for years. This is just something that's always kind of bugged me but I never devoted any time to it. I'd like to do that now. Ideally I'd be able to just add something in the web.config file like inline CSS, or perhaps link it to a .css file that will house the styles. The latter is probably preferred, actually, but any way is fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated. To get this out of the way early: yes, I have done lots and lots and lots of searching on this topic — I'm talking ***hours***. I have not been able to find a solution that seems to meet my needs. I consider posting here as somewhat of a last resort because I understand that it's a free resource and users here are usually quick to let other users know when they didn't find a particular article that seems to offer the solution they're seeking — which is usually a result of not knowing exactly what keywords to use — and I don't want to waste anyone's time. Just know that I have tried everything I know to find the solution, and that I'm genuinely stumped and looking for help from some pros.

Thank you!

Comment: Could someone please clarify the reason for the down-vote? I really put a lot of thought into this, and to be down-voted with no reason is a little bit strange. I'm trying my best to follow the etiquette and I think I hit the marks pretty well with my post. That said, I'd rather not get into a discussion about what I did or didn't do correctly; I'd rather discuss the solution so any and all pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Are the directory pages opened as new pages, or as frames inside the existing page?

Comment: Downvote wasn't me, but if I had to guess, it's because you didn't provide any code that you've already tried.  Part of a good SO question is an example using the code you've used/written that can be reproduced and tested.

Comment: All of the content is in a pretty typical file directory on the Windows machine. I have an index.html page, which kind of serves as the homepage of the intranet website. This page is completely stylized, with a handwritten .css file that the page references in the <head> section. From that page, users can click on links that take them to directories of other documents. These directories open in new pages, and they display the contents of the directory in that standard way, which I'm trying to change.

Comment: Thank you, @freginold. Perhaps I am in the wrong area, but I am so lost as to how to actually even start on this journey that there is no code to be posted — because I don't know where I would even put any code to begin with. It seems like a downvote should need to be given a reason and maybe even moderated to an extent. Oh well. I just hope that I can not only find the solution, but that my issue is not completely unique and that someone else in my position can benefit from the community's input.

Comment: Oh, so you're trying to modify the style for the directory pages? Have you tried poking around in the IIS properties window?  There might be some style-related options in there.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly correct. I just want to change the way the directory listing pages look to the visitors. I can't seem to spot the properties window of IIS.

Comment: I don't have a server in front of me to look on, but I think if you go into **Computer Management** and find **IIS** on the tree on the left side, you can right click it and choose **Properties**, and there's a few tabs that might have some web style-related settings that you can change.

Comment: Darn. I don't really see anything like that, and I've tried a number of different paths to get to something like what you describe.

Comment: Try the instructions under step #1 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/#how-to-configure-the-site-defaults-for-a-server).  You should be able to see or set the web site properties/styles from there.

Comment: Ah. Got it. Thank you. I have indeed been here before. This has a bunch of stuff not related to web page styles, at least as I can see. I wish I could post screenshots. I'm starting to get a feeling that I'm chasing a unicorn here.

Comment: Hmm. If you can't alter the style there, I'm not sure where you'd be able to do it. I don't think CSS would work, since they are not web pages. You'd probably need to code something, but I don't know what.

Comment: Rats! Well that's a bummer, but I guess "it is what it is" as they say. I'm wondering if it's just time to install a more realistic website on this server.

Comment: Looks like there might be a couple of options; maybe one of them will work for you. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Since the directory page is not HTML, you can't directly style it with CSS. However, there are a few options for changing the way it looks.

- Write a script to point to your own, custom-styled, directory page. See [this forum thread](https://www.webmasterworld.com/forum47/520.htm) for tips on how to do that and a sample script.
- Create a custom page using [this module](http://mvolo.com/get-nice-looking-directory-listings-for-your-iis-website-with-directorylistingmodule/) that you can further customize yourself.
- Use the [DirectoryListing](https://github.com/miratechcorp/DirectoryListing) open source app, which allows for customization of the directory page.

Either one of those solutions should give you more control over how the directory page looks.